# Update content on server only after I click action button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm having problems with reactive output in shiny server in R.

What I want to do is create a plotly plot that uses values calculated based on input.

The output has to be updated only after I click submit/done button and the output has to be calculated as many times as needed.

What I managed to do was to update the content independently of the submit button (the submit button simply has no function) and the plot changed immediately after I changed 1 value.

What I would like to do is to change the plot only after I specify all the values of parameters I want.

Here is a minimal example of my ui.R code:

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Wages in Year 2016 for Czech Republic in CZK"),
       sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.conditionedPanels==7",
                 selectInput("Age", "Age", choices = vek_mod$Vek, selected = "23-27"),
                 selectInput("ChosenSex", "Your sex", choices = pohlavi_mod$Pohlavie, selected = "Zena"),
                 actionButton("Button", "Done"),
                 p("Click so changes will take effect.")
      ),
        mainPanel(
         tabsetPanel(
           ...
            tabPanel("Minimal_Example", textOutput("Minimal_Example"), value = 7)
            ...
            , id = "conditionedPanels"
    )
   )
  )
 )
```

and here is the server.R code:

```
...
  output$Minimal_Example <- renderPrint({

    Age <- input$Age
    Sex <- input$ChosenSex
    c(Age, Sex)
    })
...
```

I tried a lot of things with observeEvent() as well as eventReactive() but so far nothing has worked for me.

If you want to see how the code behaves like, look here:
http://52.59.160.3:3838/sample-apps/Mzdy_ShinyApp/

Tab is called Minimal_Example

Thanks

Comment: Consider using `submitButton` instead of `actionButton`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`submitButton` is just made for this.

---

If you want to use `actionButton` instead, simply use `isolate` to avoid refresh based on value changes, and add the `input$Button`in the code like:

```
output$Minimal_Example <- renderPrint({
  input$Button
  Age <- isolate(input$Age)
  Sex <- isolate(input$ChosenSex)
  c(Age, Sex)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I didn't want to use submitButton, because official shiny documentation discouraged it: "The use of submitButton is generally discouraged in favor of the more versatile actionButton (see details below)" https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/submitButton.html