# shiny reactive output, evaluate input only after first click on actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app where the user should input comma-separated values into a text input, chose the output and click on a button to convert to an output.

I have followed the advice in [Update content on server only after I click action button in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251872/update-content-on-server-only-after-i-click-action-button-in-shiny) to change the output only when clicking, and it works.

However, only when starting/ opening the app the first time, the field is empty, yet the output seems to try to evaluate the input field.

It is more of a cosmetic problem, because once the user filled something in, this does not recur, but I wonder how I could avoid this...

My app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("from", "csv", value = NULL),

  actionButton("run", "Run"),

  textOutput("to")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  list1 <- reactive({
    input$run
    x <- isolate(paste(read.table(text = input$from, sep = ",")))
    x
  })

  output$to <- renderText({
    list1()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The not-desired output - I would like to get rid of the errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `req(input$from)`, see [Check for required values](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/req.html)

Comment: Let me know after test if this is OK!